# Почему в моем случае не работает margin-right?

Tags: html, css

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  width: 300px;
}

/*.first_p {
    background: yellow;
  margin: -10% 0 0;
}

.second_p {
    background: pink;
  margin: 0;
}*/

.first_first {
  background: yellow;
  margin: 30px 10px 0px 0px;
  width: 300px;
}

.second_second {
  background: pink;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<!--<div class="one">
        <p class="first_p">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laboriosam vel molestiae laudantium tempora obcaecati consectetur aliquid tenetur accusantium perferendis nam voluptates totam maxime, facere labore dicta consequuntur rerum officia harum.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="two">
        <p class="second_p">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laboriosam vel molestiae laudantium tempora obcaecati consectetur aliquid tenetur accusantium perferendis nam voluptates totam maxime, facere labore dicta consequuntur rerum officia harum.</p>
    </div>-->

<div class="one_one">
  <p class="first_first">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laboriosam vel molestiae laudantium tempora obcaecati consectetur aliquid tenetur accusantium perferendis nam voluptates totam maxime, facere labore dicta consequuntur rerum officia harum.</p>
</div>

<div class="two_two">
  <p class="second_second">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laboriosam vel molestiae laudantium tempora obcaecati consectetur aliquid tenetur accusantium perferendis nam voluptates totam maxime, facere labore dicta consequuntur rerum officia harum.</p>
</div>
```

P.S. Левый марджин отлично работает

Comment: вы скорее всего неправильном порядке написали значения для `margin`, порядок такой: сверху справа снизу слева

Comment: согласен, вы походу просто перепутали так как все работает

Comment: @MidNightElf `margin: 30px 10px 0px 0px;` второе значение здесь – это margin справа, который по идее должен проявляться  в 10 пикселях. Скорее дело в чем-то другом (`margin-right` как должен был идти вторым, так и идет)

Comment: @Eva ответьте на вопросы, на какой стороне расположен ваш блок? от какой стороны вы пытаетесь сделать отступ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. у вас body `{width: 300px;}` - учитывая что и блоки по 300px - негде выравниваться.
2. левый margin приоритетнее правого и 0 это не обнуление, а начало блока, т.е. его нужно поставить auto `margin: 30px 10px 0px auto;`

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

/*.first_p {
    background: yellow;
  margin: -10% 0 0;
}

.second_p {
    background: pink;
  margin: 0;
}*/

.first_first {
  background: yellow;
  margin: 30px 10px 0px auto;
  width: 300px;
}

.second_second {
  background: pink;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<!--<div class="one">
        <p class="first_p">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laboriosam vel molestiae laudantium tempora obcaecati consectetur aliquid tenetur accusantium perferendis nam voluptates totam maxime, facere labore dicta consequuntur rerum officia harum.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="two">
        <p class="second_p">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laboriosam vel molestiae laudantium tempora obcaecati consectetur aliquid tenetur accusantium perferendis nam voluptates totam maxime, facere labore dicta consequuntur rerum officia harum.</p>
    </div>-->

<div class="one_one">
  <p class="first_first">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laboriosam vel molestiae laudantium tempora obcaecati consectetur aliquid tenetur accusantium perferendis nam voluptates totam maxime, facere labore dicta consequuntur rerum officia harum.</p>
</div>

<div class="two_two">
  <p class="second_second">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laboriosam vel molestiae laudantium tempora obcaecati consectetur aliquid tenetur accusantium perferendis nam voluptates totam maxime, facere labore dicta consequuntur rerum officia harum.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: не совсем понимаю `левый margin приоритетнее правого и 0 это не обнуление, а начало блока` Насколько я знаю, margin обнуляют нулями, разве не так? И что вы имеете в виду под "начало блока"?

Comment: перерыла много информации в интернете, но так ничего и не нашла. Если не трудно, объясните в чем заключается приоритетность левого марджина

Comment: замените auto на 0 : margin: 30px 10px 0px 0 - блок окажется у левого края, а не у правого, даже если добавите !important ; В этом, по сути, и заключается приоритетность левого маржина. начало=левый край, скажем так.